# Copying a subdirectory into another folder in the same git repo

Tags: git

[Current local git repo structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAPFD.jpg)

As per the screenshot: I have a local git repo called fso_test, which has subfolders called "part3" and "part4".

Part3 currently contains the root directory of an express app, called "notes-backend".

I'd like to continue working with "notes-backend" in part4, so I need to move it to part4. I've encountered numerous problems in doing so. I've tried crude approaches such as literally copying and pasting "notes-backend" into part4, as well as more sophisticated [approaches](https://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2011/09/12/moving-one-git-repo-into-another-as-subdirectory/).

I've excluded much of the directory structure for simplicity.

Any advice?

EDIT: When I tried `cp -r notes-backend ../part4` while in part3, and then tried to stage the changes for commit, I received an error saying "warning: adding embedded git repository: course_content/part4/notes-backend".

Comment: What didn't you like about the "more sophisticated approaches"?

Comment: They didn't work. Basic commands (such as the mv!(old-project) in the link I gave) literally just didn't work, and returned an error message.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you want to do. Do you wish to move part4 around, like @ruohola suggests, or are you do you need some relative path to work from a subfolder which is why you're trying to move/copy it there? You may try symlinks, if this is the case, or you may even try to fix all your sub folders to have relative references to the base "notes-backend"

Comment: I'm working on an online course: https://fullstackopen.com/en#course-contents.

For part3 of the course, I created an express app called "notes-backend". "Notes-backend" is in the folder "part3" of the local git repo I use to house my work on the course. 

Part4 of the course requires us to make some updates to "notes-backend". So I'd like to move an exact copy of "notes-backend" from part3 into part4, so that I can continue working on "notes-backend" in part4 while preserving, in part3, the state of "notes-backend" as of the end of part3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the directory, run this **from the repo root**:

```
cp -r course_content/part3/notes-backend course_content/part4/notes-backend
git add .
git commit -m "Copy notes backend to part4"
```

Comment: I'd like to copy notes-backend, not move it. Should I use ```cp -r``` instead?

Comment: Yes you can just copy it then.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? I can assure you that those commands do "work".

Comment: @anirudhkannan9 Please try my solution again step by step. And if that gives an error, please post the full error message here.